# Intent Start Activity Loading with Delay

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-manifest

Manifest.xml

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        >
        <activity
            android:name="com.teamandy.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:name="com.teamandy.Choosetype" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:name="com.teamandy.frames1" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
         </application>
```

Main Activity:

```
this.startb=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
        this.startb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent strtint=new Intent(MainActivity.this, Choosetype.class);
                //strtint.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                strtint.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                strtint.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                strtint.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(strtint);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Choosetype Activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.choosefrm);

}
    public void f1(View v ){
        Choosetype.number=1;
        this.mcontexts=this;
        startActivity();
    }
    public void f2(View v){
        Choosetype.number=2;
        this.mcontexts=this;
        startActivity();

.........................unti f20  etc. used
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: Activity Loading with delay, taking much time for getting Choosetype Activity @Raghunandan

Comment: Try commenting out the addFlags and see what happens. Sometimes added stuff like flags or extras just randomly slows down the transition.

Comment: I am facing a similar problem when using the  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flags ...What was the solution to your problem ...please share!!